# Postfix to infix with stacks.

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm working on a project to convert from post fix notation to, fully parenthesized infix notation. The issue I am having is, it prints/stores in the reverse order it prints out as:

```
 For line: QQ=
(Q=Q)


 For line: ABC*D+*
((D+(C*B))*A)


 For line: AB+CD+EF%G--*
(((G-(F%E))-(D+C))*(B+A))


 For line: NT^G*NN+#
((N+N)#(G*(T^N)))


 For line: A
A


 For line: ABC*D+*
((D+(C*B))*A)
```

my code that reads the data in is:

```
void ReadData(string inString, ifstream& in)
{
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        stack<string> postToIn;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i< inString.length(); i++)
        {
            if ((inString[i] != '+') && (inString[i] != '-') && (inString[i] != '/') && (inString[i] != '#') &&
                (inString[i] != '*') && (inString[i] != '%') && (inString[i] != '^') && (inString[i] != '='))
            {
                string charac(1,inString[i]);

                postToIn.push(charac);
            }
            else
            {
                string temp = "";
                temp += "(";
                temp += postToIn.top();
                postToIn.pop();
                temp += inString[i];
                temp += postToIn.top();
                postToIn.pop();
                temp += ")";
                postToIn.push(temp);
            }           
        }


        while (!postToIn.empty())
        {
            cout << postToIn.top();
            postToIn.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;       
    }
}
```

I can't tell where in my code it is reversing it. I know the stacks are first out/ last in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack top will have the most recent operand which is what you want on the right side. The current implementation puts it on the left side of the operator.

```
            string temp = "";
            string temp2 = "";
            temp += "(";
            temp2 += postToIn.top(); // This is the recent operand. This needs to go on the right of the operator in infix notation
            postToIn.pop();
            temp += postToIn.top();
            postToIn.pop();
            temp += inString[i];
            temp += temp2;
            temp += ")";
            postToIn.push(temp);
```